# JavaScript Regex match including blank line

Tags: javascript, regex

How can one use javascript regex to match between `name=` , include the next blank line, and include the first word in the next line.

Thereofore, to end up with the following three matches

1. "fieldA"  value1
2. "fieldB" value2
3. "fieldC" value3

   ```
   undefined------WebKitFormBoundaryaP6MZ2PjlD5N249N
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldA"

   value1
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryaP6MZ2PjlD5N249N
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldB"

   value2
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryaP6MZ2PjlD5N249N
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldC"

   value3
   ```

I have tried

```
 var regExp = /name=(.*)/g,
 meta = [],
 matches = data.match(regExp);
```

but this results in `'name="fieldA"'`

I want  to capture up to the value, and exclude the actual 'name='

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use following regex

[Regex101 Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU9cF1/1)

```
/name="(\w+)"\n+(\w+)/
```

1. `name="`: matches it literally
2. `"(\w+)"`: Matches alphanumeric string wrapped in double-quotes and adds in first captured group
3. `\n+`: Matches one or more newlines. In this case `\n{2}` can also be used.
4. `(\w+)`: Second captured group

---

To access captured groups use `RegExp#exec` with global flag.

```
var obj = {};
var regex = /name="(\w+)"\n+(\w+)/g;
while(m = regex.exec(str)) {
    obj[m[1]] = m[2];
}
console.log(obj);
```

```js
var str = 'undefined------WebKitFormBoundaryaP6MZ2PjlD5N249N\
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldA"\
\
value1\
------WebKitFormBoundaryaP6MZ2PjlD5N249N\
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldB"\
\
value2\
------WebKitFormBoundaryaP6MZ2PjlD5N249N\
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldC"\
\
value3';

var obj = {};

// Changed the regex to use `\n*` for Demo Purpose
var regex = /name="(\w+)"\n*(\w+)/g;

while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
  obj[m[1]] = m[2];
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
/\bname=([\S\s]*?)(?=\s*-{6}|$)/gi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ6eO5/1)

This will match from `name=` till 6 hyphens or end of file.